# What is the best way to loop through an hierarchical array jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am looping though a jquery array. Is this the correct way to loop? please see the example below  . I donot want to write two if conditions to check if dataItems.hasChildren and child.hasChildren. i want to make the function easier.

```
function loop(dataItem) {
    if (dataItem.hasChildren) {
        dataItem.children.data().forEach(function(child) {
            console.log(child);
            if (child.hasChildren) {
                loop(child)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[LINK](http://dojo.telerik.com/iguSA/15)

Comment: using one of the loop constructs, `for x in y`, `for(<expr>; <expr>; <expr>;)`, `while(<expr>);` Those are the loops we get in JavaScript land, or if you can use the `Array.prototype.foreEach.call(<expr>)`

Comment: What is a "jQuery array"? In any case, can't you call `loop(child)` without the `if (child.hasChildren)` test? It will then be tested within the recursive call.